# Power series over integral change of variables

Tags: power-series

Let $y$ be given by
$$y=\int_x^\infty \frac{dx'}{(1+x'^2)^\alpha}$$
where $\alpha>1$. Is it possible to express the following as a series:
$$x(1+x^2)^{\alpha-1}=\sum a_n\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)^n$$